# Using find with regex to find a file name that begins with a month digit

Tags: regex, linux, find

I am attempting to use find with regex to find all files that begin with a number that would be within the range of a day of the month ( 01 .. 31 ).

This does not work

`find . -type f -regex '[0-3][0-9]*'`

What is a regex to confine the first two digits within the range 1..31 , but if the day is less than ten, confined to two digits ( 01, 02.. ) and so on, and use with the find command?

I have tried numerous things, looked at other stackoverflow articles and no solution mentioned in the other articles work.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not good for expressing number ranges like this. You need to break it down and match each pattern separately, ie. begining with `0`, `1` and `2`, `3`

For example:

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the following regex pattern:

```
^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])$
```

Your Linux command:

```
find . -type f -regex '^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])$'
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
^(             start of input
    3[01]      match 30 or 31
    |          OR
    [12][0-9]  match 10-29
    |          OR
    0[1-9]     match 01-09
)$             end of input
```

### Demo